# ADFS: Some Users Cannot Sign-In

Tags: authentication, adfs

I have a new ADFS implementation running on Server 2019. After setup, I tested authentication for various user accounts using the /adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx. Most of the account I tested worked fine with no issues. There are a few accounts, however, that exhibit the following behavior:

- Signing in with a wrong username/password results in an error message indicating the username/password is incorrect. This is expected and desirable.
- Signing in with correct username/password results in a page refresh, displaying the sign-in form again. There is no error message. I'll call this the *"refresh sign-in"*.

In the Security event log on the ADFS server, I see the following three events related to the "refresh sign-in":

- Event 4648 - A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.
- Event 4624 - An account was successfully logged on.
- Event 4625 - An account failed to log on (Failure reason: Unknown user name or bad password)

A few pieces of info:

- ADFS is configured to use a group managed service account called FsGmsa. It is a member of the Windows Authorization Access Group.
- "Forms" and "Microsoft Passport Authentication" is enabled as the primary authentication methods. I will eventually add Azure MFA.
- All tests have been ran in the intranet.
- All certificates are valid and haven't expired.
- I get the same results for the same users, regardless of what computer/device used.
- I cannot find any similarities or differences between the accounts that work and the accounts that don't.

Comment: I did find that “Windows Authorization Access Group” does not have access to the accounts in question. I need to do a few tests, but that may be the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Windows Authorization Access Group* did not have authority to read the *tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal* property on the accounts in question. Theses are the steps I took to fix the issue:

1. Open Active Directory Users and Computers
2. Go to the *View* menu and make sure the *Advanced Features* option is checked.
3. Open the *Properties* for the desired user account.
4. Click the *Security* tab.
5. Click the *Advanced* button.
6. Look for an *Allow* entry for the "Windows Authorization Access Group" principal.

   - If there is an entry, click the *Edit* button.
   - If there is **not** an entry, click the "Add" button.
7. The top section of the *Permission Entry* should be the following:

   - *Principal*: *Windows Authorization Access Group*
   - *Type*: *Allow*
   - *Applies to*: *This object only*
8. If this is a new entry, scroll all the way to the bottom of the window and click the *Clear all* button.
9. Add a check to the *Read tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal* property. It is close to the bottom of the list.
10. Click *OK* to close the *Permission Entry* window.
11. Click *OK* to close the *Advanced Security Settings* window.
12. Click *OK* to the account *Properties* window.

You will need to repeat steps 3-12 for the other accounts in question. Afterwards, test your accounts and they should sign-in without issue.

Comment: Your answer gave me a clue to similar problem I have been trying for months to resolve.  Now my problem is resolved by running Windows Service as Login system account.  Thank you.